# How to get the path for a collection in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I made custom index view for ActiveAdmin, and I would need to get the admin path for the given collection.
Here is what I have:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class IndexAsSpecial < ::ActiveAdmin::Component

      def build(page_presenter, collection)
        //...
        //  should be something like /admin/posts
        path_to_collection = ???  

        //...
      end

     def self.index_name
       "special"
     end
end
```

I have searched and tried, but all I found is paths for a resource, not for the collection (e.g. `resource.route_collection_path` )
I also found this, but here I am still missing the right parameters, or maybe the class name of the active admin collection:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.polymorphic_path([:admin,:posts])
```

Just that I need to replace `:posts` somehow dynamically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I must say, that the documentation of ActiveAdmin is very vague here, but after debugging a bit more I found the answer to my question:

`helpers.collection_path # will generate /admin/posts`

or if you need a member action on the collection:

`helpers.resource_path(:action_name) # will generate /admin/posts/action_name`